# TypeError: _models_test__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Test.create is not a function

Tags: mongoose, next.js

As soon as I click the save button I get the error in the title.

Here are my files -

Test Model

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


    name: String,
    age: Number
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    })

export const Test = mongoose.model("test", testSchema)
```

I tried default export too but the error persisted

File I'm importing it in (page.js)

```js
import '../styles/tiptap.scss'

import { connectToDB } from "../../utils/database"
import { Test } from "../../models/test"

async function saveToDB() {
  await connectToDB();
  const test = await Test.create({ name: "Jhon", age: 30 })
  test.save();
  return 0
}


const Tiptap = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={saveToDB}>Save</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tiptap
```